# Keyboard appears when click on help icon inside textfield

Tags: flutter

How do I stop the keyboard from appearing if the user clicks on this help icon... Here is a screenshot

Any type of help will greatly appreciated

[image]

Here is my code

```
TextFormField(
                                obscureText: false,
                                controller: urlController,
                              validator: (value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter instagram url';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                  },
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1.0),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  ),

                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.green),
                                  ),
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  labelText: 'Paste Your URL',
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: (){},
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                                    iconSize: 30.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  ),
                                ),
                            )
```

Comment: give a try to onIconTap `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: (){
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
//or FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                                    iconSize: 30.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  ),
```

[EDITED]

or simple use Stack to avoid touching Textfield when touching icon:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      child: Container(
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        child: IconButton(onPressed:(){}, icon: Icon(Icons.add),),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: is there any other way than this ```FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();```

Comment: FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());

Comment: Your code not working as expected... keyboard appears when I first click on the icon and when i again click on the icon the keyboard disappear.............   my question is how to not show keyboard in any way if the icon is being clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use `suffix` property instead of `suffixIcon` and if it still doesn't work on its own, wrap it with a `IgnorePointer` widget.

However, I assume that that `?` button will have a `onTap` function, if so, it should then it shouldn't be a problem.

```
  suffix: IgnorePointer(
        child:IgnorePointer(
          child: IconButton(
           onPressed: () {},
           icon: Icon(Icons.help),
           iconSize: 30.0,
           color: Colors.grey[400],
      ),
    );
   ),
```

Comment: your ignore pointer seems to work but it increases my text field size and also the icon disappear when the text field is not in focus.

Comment: Keep the `suffixIcon` then. The `IgnorePointer` shouldn't have any impact on layout constraints, hence, the size should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

suffixIcon is now part of the TextField so we cannot do it using focus node as per changes made by flutter team.

However you can create your layout with Stack widget.

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, children: [
                TextFormField(
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  obscureText: false,
                  controller: urlController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter instagram url';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    labelText: 'Paste Your URL',
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.help,
                    size: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ])),
```

Or you can use  use **CupertinoTextField**

Answer (score 0):

```
stack(
  children: [
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      child: Container(
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        child: IconButton(onPressed:(){}, icon: Icon(Icons.add),),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```